# Single Quotes in Emmet With VS Web Essentials

Tags: html, visual-studio, web-essentials, emmet

Is there a way how to force Visual Studio Web Essentials to insert single quotes instead of double quotes?

For instance so that `div.col-xs-1` <kbd>TAB</kbd> produces `<div class='col-xs-1'></div>` instead of default `<div class="col-xs-1"></div>`?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with Web Essentials 2013 v. 2.5.3.

Answer (score 19):

Not to be a johnny come lately, but I was having trouble getting this to work in VS code, and so I thought I would post a solution for anyone still having this problem.  My solution was to go into settings (ctrl-,) > user settings > extensions > emmet and under preferences click "Edit in settings.json".  There, I added this to the user settings:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "xml": {
        "attr_quotes": "single"
    },
    "html": {
        "attr_quotes": "single"
    },
    "js": {
        "attr_quotes": "single",
        "self_closing_tag": true
    },
    "jsx": {
        "attr_quotes": "single",
        "self_closing_tag": true
    }
}
```

Where each language you can define settings for.  This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I was in a deep rabbit hole trying to figure this out. This is the solution that helped me (VS Code ver 1.42.0). To be explicit, added the code you provided to my `settings.json` file for Code - I did not create a separate file or directory.

Comment: Thanks for this! I did ctrl + shift + p to get into the popup. I searched 'settings json'. Click on 'Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)'. Then added the above settings at the very bottom and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This question was regarding using VS Web essentials with Visual Studio (Not VS Code)

Comment: doesnt work in vs code

Comment: This is the only bloody solution that worked for me like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get single quotes working with JSX you will need to update or create the `syntaxProfiles.json` in `~/emmet` with the syntax profile. If `~/emmet` does not exist create it.

The key is the file extension and the value is the name of the profile that extension will use.

So in `~/emmet/syntaxProfiles.json`

```
/* 'js' will map files with .js extension to use the js profile*/
/* 'jsx' will map files with .jsx extension to also use the js profile*/
{
  "js": "js",
  "jsx": "js"
}
```

And in `~/emmet/profiles.json`

```
/* create or add the 'js' profile */
{
  "html": {
    "attr_quotes": "double"
  },
  "js": {
    "attr_quotes": "single",
    "self_closing_tag": true
  }
}
```

This should work for most editors but I have only tried in atom. 
https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/68